# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC Calculate Salary with Employee Rank

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on an MVC application. And I want to create employees.
When I create employees I add a rank between 1-10.
And I want this rank to multiply with a constant salary coefficent.
For example, I create an employee with the rank of 5.
When creating this, I want the rank of 5 to multiply with an constant salary coefficent on, for example 1.125.

My Model:

```
public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("First Name")]
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Name")]
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Rank")]
        [Range(1, 10)]
        [Required]
        public decimal Salary { get; set; }
        public bool IsCEO { get; set; }
        public bool IsManager { get; set; }
        public int ManangerId { get; set; }
    }
```

and here is my create function in my controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName,Salary,IsCEO,IsManager,ManangerId")] Employee employee)
        {
            //Employee CalculateSalary = _context.Employees.FirstOrDefault(
            //    s => s.Salary == CalculateSalary.Salary);

            
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(employee);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(employee);
        }
```

Any idea on how I could do this? Could this be done in my controller or something else? Maybe some kind of helper class?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC (on the full, classic .NET Framework) - or ASP.NET **Core** MVC on .NET Core?? You're not very consistent and precise with your description and tags....

Comment: Im sorry, I mean asp.net core, or the new .net 5. Which is basically the same I think.

Comment: You could create a new component, e.g. ISalaryCalculator. Add an operation to calculate the salary based on rank. Then simply inject this calculator where you want to use it. By having it in a separate component you can easily write unit tests for it and adjust logic later on if calculation rules change.

Comment: For per Ranks, whether it contains different coefficient, for example, Rank 5 -> 1.125, Rank 10 -> 2? If they have the same coefficient, before adding the new employee to the database, you could calculate the salary like this: `employee.Salary = employee.Salary * (decimal)1.125;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddEmployee([Bind("Id,FirstName,LastName,Salary,IsCEO,IsManager,ManangerId")] Employee employee)
            {
                //Added this code
                var coefficent = (employee.IsCEO) ? 2.725 : (employee.IsManager) ? 1.725 : 1.125;
                employee.Salary = Convert.ToDecimal(coefficent) * employee.Salary;
                
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    _context.Add(employee);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                return View(employee);
            }
```